# Xcode 15 Messages.app in simulator - sample users are not able to send-receive each other

Tags: ios, xcode15

Xcode 15 (RC)

This worked in Xcode 14.3+, AFAIR.

Messages provides two users (with placeholder phone numbers). When you type and send in one, it is received by the other (rather than go out to the real service).

In Xcode 15, when I send a message, I see the activity (dots) animation in either the sender or the receiver (but never both). The message never arrives.

In previous Xcode versions, the user-loopback did work, you could switch between the two accounts and have conversation with your self.

I've tried erasing the simulator, as well as doing Simulator.app quit, and restarting the simulated instance.

Any ideas?

My actual goal is to return to developing an iMessage extension.